# Connecting PC to (a no smart) TV wirelessly without internet

Tags: hdmi, desktop-computer, tv

I would to connect my PC to (a no smart) TV wirelessly without internet. The PC is in a room, whereas the TV is two rooms ahead. The TV has hdmi input. I tried google chromecast, but it need internet. I won't use a cell to create an hotspot.

---

EDIT: if possible, I would like to avoid solutions which involve smartphone.

Thank you very much.

Comment: An android tv stick should be more than enough for your need. There are many alternatives on the market (none i'll name here because of obvious reasons :) )

Comment: Please specify PC CPU model and TV model, the only option is DLNA, Chromecast hack or Intel WiDi

Comment: Hi dExIT, I have CPU intel i7, now i can't see the model of TV (later I add this information).

Answer (score 0):

**This is a way to "hack" chromecast, first enable with Mobiledata, and then disable after pairing/setup is succesfull but Casting will be still available.**

Gather two devices

One must be an Android cell phone with mobile hotspot capability

The second can be any device that is capable of casting local media

open "settings" on cell phone

open "more networks"

select "mobile hotspot"

turn on "mobile hotspot"

go into "mobile hotspot" settings by selecting the 3 vertical dots in the upper-right corner

select configure hotspot

type in a name you would like to call your mobile hotspot network or leave the default name

scroll down to choose a password for this network

Now we must switch the Wi-Fi network that the Chromecast is paired to.
ensure that the second device (the one you wish to cast from) is connected to 
the same network that the Chromecast is paired to (the pairing was done when you first setup your Chromecast)
open the Chromecast app (if using iOS or Android) or open Chrome if using Linux, Windows, or MacOS

From the app choose the name of the Chromscast or from Chrome select the Chromecast icon in the upper-right of the screen and then choose the name of the Chromecast

Select "Wi-Fi"

Select the name of the network you are on (this will drop-down a menu with other networks)

Select the name of the mobile hotspot network you created and enter password
This will successfully switch the network that the Chromecast looks to connect to

Now we will open LocalCast app and cast the video we desire. And lastly we will go back to the cell phone and turn off "mobile data" and leave on "mobile hotspot"

Source : https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/38sb3v/lpt_use_chromecast_without_internetmobile_data_by/crxfse8

Comment: Hi @dExIT, I won't use an internet connection (the hotspot of cell use internet).

Comment: Please READ, before commenting, THIS IS NEEDED just to ENABLE CHromeCast Pairing, then after pariing is succesful you DISABLE MOBILE DATA, and HOTSPOT Does not USE MOBILE DATA if you disable it.

Comment: And please try it before saying something is not happening. And you have not still provided any solid information.

CPU I7 but which model >? i7-2630 ? i7-3320 ? is it a laptop ?